# Android Data Binding Add widget as a parameter of binding adapter

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I want to run the visible the progressbar until the image load into imageview. I want to implement it through binding adapter. I have a CustomBinder class which has a bindingadpter of imageUrl. This is my custom binder-

```
public class CustomBinders {

    static ImageLoader imageLoader;
    public static DisplayImageOptions options;
    private static final String TAG = "CustomBinders";

    @BindingAdapter({"imageUrl"})
    public static void loadImage(ImageView view, String imageUrl){
        imageLoader= ImageLoader.getInstance();
        options = StaticMethods.setUIL();
        Log.d(TAG, "loadImage: ");
        imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, view, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                String message = null;
                switch (failReason.getType()) {
                    case IO_ERROR:
                        message = "Input/Output error";
                        break;
                    case DECODING_ERROR:
                        message = "Image can't be decoded";
                        break;
                    case NETWORK_DENIED:
                        message = "Downloads are denied";
                        break;
                    case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                        message = "Out Of Memory error";
                        break;
                    case UNKNOWN:
                        message = "Unknown error";
                        break;
                }
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blank);

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

In my xml their is a progressbar and i want to visible the progrssbar untill the image loading is complete. That is my xml with data bind.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <data class="ArtListCreatedByBind">
        <variable
            name="artlist"
            type="com.twebexponent.artwork.data.ArtListCreatedBy"/>
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/myContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@drawable/manageartwork_border">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/art_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:imageUrl="@{artlist.image}"
            />
    </FrameLayout>



</layout>
```

And this was before when i simply calling the view using binding not by calling BindingAdapter.

```
viewDataBinding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageLoader.displayImage(artListModel.getImage(), viewDataBinding.artImg, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                String message = null;
                switch (failReason.getType()) {
                    case IO_ERROR:
                        message = "Input/Output error";
                        break;
                    case DECODING_ERROR:
                        message = "Image can't be decoded";
                        break;
                    case NETWORK_DENIED:
                        message = "Downloads are denied";
                        break;
                    case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                        message = "Out Of Memory error";
                        break;
                    case UNKNOWN:
                        message = "Unknown error";
                        break;
                }

                viewDataBinding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewDataBinding.artImg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blank);

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                viewDataBinding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

Now in above code i am visible the progressbar first time and then when the images load has done that time i simply gone the progressbar. Now the same approch how i will do this using @BindingAdapter({"imageUrl"})??

This is what my adapter look like of recylerview-

```
public class ArtistCreatedByAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArtistCreatedByAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {


    ArrayList<ArtListCreatedBy> createdByArtList;
    Activity activity;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    public DisplayImageOptions options;
    ArtListCreatedByBind viewDataBinding;

    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ArtListCreatedByBind mViewDataBinding;

        public CustomViewHolder( View v) {
            super(v);

            mViewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.bind(v);
            mViewDataBinding.executePendingBindings();

        }

        public ArtListCreatedByBind getViewDataBinding() {
            return mViewDataBinding;
        }
    }

    public ArtistCreatedByAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<ArtListCreatedBy> createdByArtList) {
        this.activity = activity;
        imageLoader= ImageLoader.getInstance();
        this.createdByArtList = createdByArtList;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singlerow_art_list_created_by, parent, false);

        return new CustomViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        ArtListCreatedBy artListModel= createdByArtList.get(position);
        viewDataBinding = holder.getViewDataBinding();

        viewDataBinding.setArtlist(artListModel);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return createdByArtList.size();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bind another parameter with your `BindingAdapter` method

```
@BindingAdapter({"imageUrl","progressbar"})
public static void loadImage(ImageView view, String imageUrl, ProgressBar progressBar){
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

now pass your progressBar from xml like this :

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/art_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:imageUrl="@{artlist.image}"
        app:progressbar="@{progressBar}"/>
```

**Note** : here `progressBar` will be id of your `ProgressBar`

Comment: OK thanks for your answer i am trying and get back to you within 5mints.

Comment: glad to help you, enjoy coding :)

Comment: No really thanks to you because after searching so many things in google i don't found the proper answer but i found some answer which is similar to your answer but i am failed to implement it properly...
http://angelolloqui.com/blog/35-Improving-your-Android-apps-with-Data-Bindings

Comment: Just for more clarification...progressBar in this line app:progressbar="@{progressBar} is `id` of your ProgressBar.

Comment: @KetanAhir yes that will be id of progressbar

Comment: Yeah...I got it. But just mentioned so that it can be helpful to others.